# String Formatting for SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

If I have a database table that looks like this:

```
| ID |    FirstName    |    LastName    |
_________________________________________

   1         John              Doe
   2         Test             Subject
```

And I want to create a dropdownlist of full names, how would I go about doing so?

```
var fullNameSelectList = new SelectList(db.Test, "ID", "FirstName"); // Gives me a ddl of only firstnames

var fullNameSelectList = new SelectList(db.Test, "ID", "FirstName" + "LastName"); // Gives me error, database doesn't contain property with name FirstNameLastName
```

Is there a way to combine those properties within the SelectList overload?

I know I can create a ViewModel, but I just want to know if this is possible first.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a Stored Procedure to access your data?  I've always concatenated the names in the proc (or the query) and called them something like LastFirst - then bind with that.

Comment: @EricBurdo No I am not using Stored Procedure.  Using EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
var fullNameSelectList = new SelectList(
     db.Test.Select(x => new {x.ID, FullName = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName}).ToArray(), 
    "ID", "FullName");
```

Comment: Okay, now how do receive that FullName value in the `selectedValue` option of the SelectList overload?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid think that this is should be different question.